# How to retrieve data from json output

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json output that looks like this.

```
{
   "38467": {
      "name": "Tony Parker",
      "book": [
         {
            "title": {
               "name": "MediaWorks"
            },
         },
       ],
   }
   "59678": {
      "name": "Ray Thomas",
   }
}
```

Actually json output is a lot bigger list. But I want to only save author's name and their publisher. I want save multiple individual records for a single model.

I am using jquery to assign input elements their values.

```
  $('#Author' + i + 'Title').val(response...);
```

But it is not working.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is just javascript data - a javascript object. Assign the "decoded" JSON data to a variable (say `var dat`), then you can access members the normal object/array away: `dat[38467]['name']` is `Tony Parker` and so on.

comment update:

once you've decoded/stored the data, you can use a regular javascript foreach loop to go over it:

```
for (var bookID in booklist) {
   var author = booklist[bookID]['name'];
   var title =  booklist[bookID]['book'][0]['title']['name'];
   // ...do stuff here...
}
```

There's nothing magical about JSON, it's just javascript data packed up for easy/clean transmission. Of course, if you're using a framework such as jQuery or MooTools, you'd be better off using their own `.each()` operators, otherwise you'll get various bits of useless fluff from the `for()` loop.

edit: fixed code sample as per marimuthu's comment (good catch, thanks).

Comment: I am looking something like for loop which loops through it and gives us the variable. I apologize, i am new to computer programming.. and have lots to learn.

Comment: I use JQuery a lot, but if there is one thing I avoid using it for, it is loops. .each() loop does not scale well! Anyway good info +1.

Comment: 'book' property is an array hence we need to access through its index:
var title =  booklist[bookID]['book'][0]['title']['name'];